# Find entities dependent on other entities (via DB ForeignKeys) in DataContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am writing some very generic database code, and I would like to find a way to query a set of types in my entity set (using LINQ to SQL EntityFramework, database-first) which are related to another entity.

So, for example I might have a Product belong to a Category;

```
SELECT * FROM Products p INNER JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryId = c.Id
```

In my database, p.CategoryId is a Foreign Key constrain to be NON-NULL. (i.e; a Product MUST belong to a Category).

Now, if I try to DELETE FROM Categories, I get errors, as there are Products still related to Categories, and I do not have (or want) a CASCADE DELETE applied to the relationship.

What I want to do is examine my DataContext library, and determine dynamically that Categories are key'd by Products, and so if I want to DELETE from Categories, I will first need to DELETE from Products.

By 'dynamically', I mean that my code will not have fore-knowledge of the types or relationships (it does not know about Product or Category entities specifically) but I am willing to use Reflection to assess the DLL to work out these relationships.

I have looked at the DataContext-related code, and can see EntityRef properties on certain Entities (which is half the problem solved), but I can't seem to find any way to tell if these relationships are mandatory or optional (i.e; NON-NULL or NULLABLE) in the underlying database.

?

Answer (score 0):

You know you can automatically cascade deletes in Entity Framework by setting the Delete Rule to "Cascade"? That may make things easier (while not necessarily providing a generic solution for LINQ to SQL).

Take a look here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx

Comment: I assume you mean by modifying properties on the EF model? That's the only way I know how to do this, but that approach isn't appropriate here, as I don't want to modify the model. I actually want to prevent this action in normal usage, but find a way to bypass it, or at least assess it so I can delete entities in the correct order.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I meant using the model properties.